# Allocation of large permanent arrays as std::vector or std::array?

Tags: arrays, c++11, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm progrmaming the 3D [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) on C++. This model consists in a 3D lattice containing the spins which are then updated to simulate different random configurations (Monte Carlo Simulation). To speed up the code I also store the nearest neighbors of each site in a vector/array.

Since I'm not a very expert of C++, I would like to ask you what is the most performant way/better practice for storing such sequences. Personally, I would initialize the lattice and the nearest neighbors in a static STL array (i.e. on the stack), since the size of these arrays never changes and the arrays are also never destroyed until program end.

Is this good or bad practice? Or would it be better to store them as STL vectors?

Comment: If you know at compile time the size use array. Pay attention if you create array on the stack because its size is limited (even if configurable).

Comment: @alangab If they are declared as `std::array<int, numel> s{ };` I have problem due to stack size if numel is too big. However, if i declare them as `static std::array<int, numel> s{ };`the stack size is automatically increased, right?

Comment: @david23 No, stack size isn't increased; But (locally) static and global variables aren't allocated on the stack at all, so that's not an issue. So in any case you're right that if your variable is static its size isn't that important and won't lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: @david23: If these arrays are on the stack, then by definition they are not "permanent". Everything on the stack is temporary.

Comment: If `numel` is big, eben if they fit on your stack fine, this might not increase performance, which is what you said you were trying to achieve. Profile your code and see what's slow. Can you paralise the calculations in suitable sized chunks (read about cache lines and memory) ?

Comment: "To speed up the code I also store the nearest neighbors of each site in a vector/array." -- with fixed size array, finding nearest neighbors is a matter of mere integer mathematics.  Unless the data is large, storing 6 pointers is probably going to ruin your cache more than doing math is going to cost you in cycles.

Comment: Large objects do not go on the stack; most implementations have relatively small stacks.  The overhead of heap allocation isn't high for medium large buffers (compared to the effort, say, of initializing the data)  For extremely large buffers single large heap allocations are less appropriate; consider breaking your buffer up (especially in 32 bit systems).

Comment: @doctorlove Ok, thanks. Yes, the parallelization should be possible, but it is not what I'm aiming at right now.

Comment: @Yakk What do you exactly mean with "ruining your cache"? I simulate systems with size `numel` between 50^3 and 500^3 with approx 10k MC steps (in each of which I flip _all_ the spins - better say I flip `numel` spins chosen randomly)

Comment: @david your cpu cache.  More memory used means more problems.  I would "tile" things if most calculations are local and do seams separately for that reason as well.

Comment: @Yakk Sorry, I forgot to say that I am simulating infinite systems by using periodic boundary conditions, so calculating the nearest neighbors isn't mere integer mathematics

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `std::vector` how big it will be in advace.

Alternatively, you can use `std::array` now if it will remain fixed size.
For example,

```
std::array<int, 10> neighbours;
```

for 10 ints.